# Reference sub-property in another property

Tags: typescript

Say i have

```
type QueryPlanType = {
  [key: string]: {
    (): {
      key: string
      data: Record<string, string | number>    
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible using type definition to make sure that `key` is always one of the keys from the data list.

```
{
    test: () => ({
      key: 'foo',
      data: {
        foo: 1
        bar: 2
      }
    }),
}
```

so because data has a **foo** property, we are allowed to specify the key **equal** to **foo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to ensure that `key` is always typed the way you expect:

```
// Add generic type T to QueryPlanType
type QueryPlanType<T extends string> = {
    [key: string]: {
        (): {
            key: T,
            data: Record<T, string | number>
        }
    }
}


// Example:
type Keys = "foo" | "bar";

// This works
const validQueryPlan: QueryPlanType<Keys> = {
    test: () => ({
        key: "foo",
        data: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2
        }
    })
}

// This doesnt
const invalidQueryPlan: QueryPlanType<Keys> = {
    test: () => ({
        key: "baz",
        data: {
            foo: 1,
            bar: 2
        }
    })
}
```

Note that when you do `Record<T, string|number>`, there must *always* be both a `foo` key and a `bar` key on that object.

Hope this helps - good luck!